# Angular 2 in-memory-web-api intercept custom actions?

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api

How can I do custom actions with in-memory-web-api?  I need to call...

```
http://example.com/api/products/getbyname/widget
```

getbyname is not "resty", so I'm not sure how to intercept it and return something.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you want to get (a list of) `widget` of a product.

You can just get record(s) from table in DB.

For example: you have `products` table; each `product` has `widget` property. In this case, you have to get `product` from `products` table, and then, get `widget` return from product.

If you want to get product info by name, try to call:

`http://example.com/api/products/?productName=${productName}`
*(Query product by name)*

or

`http://example.com/api/products/${productId}`
*(Query product by id)*

Then get `widget` return from result.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm using in-memory-web-api in angular2, so in this case, I don't want to touch my database.  I don't even want to touch an api.  I'd like to cause in-memory-web-api to intercept a custom action that doesn't fall into the RESTful pattern of http://example.com/resourcename/:id, and return something.  If my question wasn't clear, please let me know how I can be more clear.